# What does Barney say and mean?

Tags: dialogue, how-i-met-your-mother

It's in season 8 episode 3 of [*How I Met Your Mother*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460649/) at 8:22min. I found it on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzyYvNyMo0k#t=3m3s) too.

> "Barney!!!" "Icksnay on the ealray amenay!" "Mr and Mrs Erikson?"
>   "Youuu son of a... itchbay!"

The itch-Bay was easy.
And to me the previos is: Nicks on the real name!
But what does that mean? A referrence to the NY nicks?
I don't get it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not "icksnay".  It's "ixney", which is "nix", as in stop talking about it.  He's telling them not to mention his real name in front of the woman he's trying to fool.

Comment: hank-tay you! It haunted me for days...

Comment: You're welcome.  And on a side note, the appropriate pig latin for "thank" is "ankthay". :D  It goes to the first vowel.

Comment: Zazu also uses " ixnay on the oopid-stay" in The Lion King.

Answer (score 7):

He's using [Pig Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) and the specific word he's saying is '[ixnay](http://www.allwords.com/query.php?SearchType=3&Keyword=ixnay&goquery=Find%20it!&Language=ENG)' which means 'no'.

Comment: Nix means to veto or reject.